# WCF Service is not hosted on the machine

Tags: c#, wcf

I have implemented a simple chat console app and it worked well. When i tried to apply the same concept on GUI app. the service side when hosting , there is any error but if i use CMD command netstat -ao to show all ports , it is not exists.So when i run client app , there is an Exception (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused). How can i solve these problem ?

Server

```
ServiceHost host;
using (host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:4111")))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new NetTcpBinding(), "IService");

    try
    {
        host.Open();

    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Client

```
public bool Connect()
{
    DuplexChannelFactory<IService> pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IService>(new InstanceContext(this),
                                                                                    new NetTcpBinding(),
                                                                                    new EndpointAddress(AppConfiguration.GetValue(net.tcp://localhost:4111/IService"));

    try
    {
        pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
        if (pipeProxy.Register())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the client from the same computer as the server? If not, `net.tcp://localhost:4111` is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve it.
In GUI remove the (using) at defined new ServiceHost. Why i don't know but it works!!!

```
ServiceHost host;
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:4111"));
```

Comment: Don't do this! `using` is syntactic sugar for controlled disposal of resources. The reason this 'works' is because you've removed the code that disposes of the ServiceHost when it's finished with. It isn't clear from your question exactly what the problem is, but you should definitely reinstate the `using` block. It exists for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are showing all your code.

You need to add a line after host.Open();, you could add Console.ReadLine();

This would get the program to stop from existing. What happens now is that the host opens, then the program exists, and the host gets closed/garbage collected.